# How to reshape pandas 2d MultiIndex to numpy 3d faster?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, 3d, reshape

I have the following code that works well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = pd.DataFrame({'CaseID':[1,1,2,2],
              'col1':  [1,2,1,2],
              'col2':  [1,1,2,2]})
X.set_index(['CaseID','col1'], inplace=True) #MultiIndex

Unique_Cases = X.index.levels[0]
print(Unique_Cases)
#[1, 2]

D = [X.loc[Case].values for Case in Unique_Cases]
print(np.array(D).shape)
#(2, 2, 1)
```

But the problem is that I have 50 million records and it takes a lot of time (10 hours).
There is a faster way to turn 2d pandas to 3d numpy array?

## clarification:

```
len(X.loc[Case])
```

Not always the same length.

## Solution:

```
case_counts = X.CaseID.value_counts().to_frame('counts').sort_index()
case_counts['count_cumsum'] = case_counts.counts.cumsum()
#drop the last row for split
case_counts.drop(case_counts.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
cat_values = X[cat].values
cat_values = np.split(cat_values, case_counts.count_cumsum)
```

Comment: For each `Case` in `Unique_Cases`, is `len(X.loc[Case])` always the same?

Comment: No, that's exactly the problem.
I have seen many solutions to situations in which the amount of records is the same but unfortunately this is not the case here :(

Comment: Suppose `X = pd.DataFrame({'CaseID':[1,1,1,2], 'col1':  [1,2,1,2], 'col2':  [1,1,2,2]})`. What is the desired result? Your code would produce `D` with shape `(2,)`.

Comment: NumPy arrays are N-dimensional "rectangular" arrays. Each axis has a fixed length. If you try to convert a ragged list of lists (e.g. `[[1,1,2], [2]]`) into a NumPy array, NumPy returns a *one-dimensional* array of objects: `np.array([[1,1,2], [2]], dtype='object')`. There is no (useful) way to turn this into a 3D array.

Comment: The non-useful way to turn this into a 3D array is: `np.array([[1,1,2], [2]], dtype='object').reshape(-1,1,1)`, which has shape `(2, 1, 1)`. But tacking extra axes (with length 1) on to the end of an array does not seem to serve any useful purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is np.split :

```
case_counts = X.CaseID.value_counts().to_frame('counts').sort_index()
case_counts['count_cumsum'] = case_counts.counts.cumsum()
#drop the last row for split
case_counts.drop(case_counts.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
cat_values = X[cat].values
cat_values = np.split(cat_values, case_counts.count_cumsum)
```